# How do I extend my root partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, root

I have tried some other questions about extending root partitions but they haven't worked for me. Is there any possible way that I can shrink my home partition and extend my root partition with the extra free space?[image]

Comment: Note the PADLOCK symbols, you can't resize partitions whilst they are in-use.  Me I'd just delete the swap, re-size as you want, then re-create the swap later. UUIDs on the new *swap* will differ, but that's easily corrected (or you can use a *swapfile* instead & just comment out the partition references.. depending on your *unstated* release)

Comment: You're really lucky that the swap partition is adjacent to the root partition.  Swap partitions are over-rated in the modern distros and more plentiful RAM.  You could do exactly as guiverc says.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to fix my issue by booting with a usb and "trying ubuntu". From there I used gparted to resize partitions.